# How to use MySQL database for nopCommerce framework?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, nopcommerce

nopCommerce provides all the requirements for my project except that I want to use MySQL as my database Engine.
Are there any existing Database Driver class like there are in CodeIgniter which will allow me to use MySQL as my db engine.

I'm new to .NET so if there is no such kind of driver then can you help me building a new one from scratch?

P.S.
I've done some research on this and found that following links might be useful

[How to make MySQL support lib - But I was not able to make one :(](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/17712/mysql-support.aspx)

[Another Forum topic didn't helped me much..](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/17783/working-on-mysql-for-26-now.aspx)

It would be great if anyone could even help me with the development approach.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged 'sql-server'?

Comment: Yes, Currently the nopCommerce framework uses SQL-server so need to make it work with MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fork of version 2.60 that claims to use mySQL:

https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/bmeine/MySql

Answer (score 0):

I added the MySQL Support for 4.1 version with minimum code changes.
Some features like full text searching and some options at product search page not implemented yet.

Here is the code:
https://github.com/turgayozgur/nopCommerce

Just, use the master branch to run the nopCommerce on MySQL database.

[Here is the installation page preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye59N.png)